# Observer not firing if order status changes to complete

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to do some action when the order status changes to complete. Here is my code

app/etc/modules/changeorderstatus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Changeorderstatus_status>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Changeorderstatus_status>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Changeorderstatus/status/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Changeorderstatus_status>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Changeorderstatus_status>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_status_change>
                <observers>
                    <Changeorderstatus_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Changeorderstatus_status_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </Changeorderstatus_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_status_change>
        </events>

    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Changeorderstatus/status/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Changeorderstatus_status_Model_Observer
{
    public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $status = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus();
        $originalData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getOrigData();
        $previousStatus = $originalData['status'];


        if (($status !== $previousStatus) && ($status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)) {
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

If the state of any order changes to complete it should fire automatically.
I changed the order from canceled to completed manually but it is not firing

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is the event you are triggering.

There is no event like `sales_order_status_change`, You should try with `sales_order_save_after`.

for me it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Now try this**

> app/etc/modules/Changeorder_Status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Changeorder_Status>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Changeorder_Status>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Changeorder/Status/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Changeorder_Status>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Changeorder_Status>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <status>
        <class>Changeorder_Status_Helper</class>
      </status>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <status>
        <class>Changeorder_Status_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>status_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </status>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_status_change> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_order_status_change_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>status/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>implementOrderStatus</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </sales_order_status_change_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_status_change>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Changeorder/Status/Model/Observer.php

```
        public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $status = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getStatus();
            $originalData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getOrigData();
            $previousStatus = $originalData['status'];

            if (($status !== $previousStatus) && ($status == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE)) {
                exit();
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: I did the changes  and changed the order status from processing to complete but  it is not exiting